# My android studio is not updating from 3.5 to 3.6 version

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm trying to update my android studio 3.5 to the newer version 3.6 , a pop up dialog shows up asking to me update to version 3.6 , i click update and restart , it starts downloading but once it is finished , it dosn't show any pop up dialog or message to restart my android studio  , i event tried to restart android studio to see if the it is updated , it shows again version 3.5 , i did update android studio many times to 3.6 version but it keeps showing version 3.5 , any help would be appreciated guys , thank you

Comment: can't you just download a new version of 3.6 by uninstalling the old one

Comment: but if i install it manually , do i have to download everything again like the sdk , platforms and so on , because my internet speed is not fast

Comment: i'm not sure but it might be possible to avoid doing this, will probably be faster than constantly doing a 300mb+ update and not getting anywhere :)

Comment: @takieddine you can use the old path in the new installation and moreover, the studio will take it through previous version config.

Comment: well yeah it sounds logic if i have to keep installing 300 mb of data every time

Comment: Rajen , do you mean i provide the old path of my android studio once the new one starts installing ?

Comment: Just delete folder of your older Android Studio (v3.5), you can't have both 3.5 and 3.6 in your system.

Comment: i downloaded it manually , when the installation process started ,it asked to either use old config and make a new one , i picked the old now and now it is installed and working fine , thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the newest in the website (not from inside Android Studio) from your browser and install it.

You can choose :

a.) to uninstall the old version first before installing the new version

b.) or just installing the new one that automatically detects the old one and asks u to remove the old version and then it will install the new version.. then u just have to follow the instruction...

I actually encountered this problem yesterday, by update it from inside the Android Studio, and then I tried to manually download it from the website using my browser and it worked.

Comment: Did you have to install everything again like the sdks , platforms and so on , because i have downloaded it manualy  already but i didnt want to risk uninstalling the old one until i make sure what to do

Comment: @takieddine i actually forgot about that,.. but if you choose to install it while the old version still intact it will ask u to update it and choosing the (old or new) configuration ..

Comment: i downloaded it manually , when the installation process started ,it asked to either use old config and make a new one , i picked the old now and now it is installed and working fine , thank you mate